# How to log in on this website (single page application)

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, scrape

I learn to scrape, and I want to log in on a Single Page Application, How can i do to input something

https://web.iflrs-lamusse.net/MyKomunote/index.php

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a tutorial, which isn't on topic for SO. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are good tutorials on submitting web form data, so give that a go, and if you get stuck, come back here and we will be happy to help

Comment: I have already done a lot of research and asked several questions (not exclusively on this account though) but I still can't figure it out

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I tried to find where can i input the password and the pseudo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.